# How to extract all the values of one array and assign those values to another array

Tags: javascript

if array1  = [1, 2, 3, 4];

then array2 = [5, 6, 7];

In the end i want all these values to be in one array as

array3 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

Comment: Did you try anything ?

Answer (score -1):

You can use [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) method like this

```js
let array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];

let array2 = [5, 6, 7];

let array3 = array1.concat(array2);

console.log(array3)
```

Comment: Please flag such clear duplicates instead of answering